# What is the name of this bird from Tanzania?

Tags: species-identification, zoology, ornithology

[image]

I took this picture in late 2018 in Tanzania. The Birds of East Africa book does not include it and I've been unable to identify it looking on the web. Can someone help me identify it, please. Thank you!

Answer (score 6):

That looks like a [knob-billed duck](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knob-billed_duck).

Their range includes Sub-Saharan Africa, India, and Southeast Asia.

[image: picture of a knob-billed duck in a pond]

[Picture source](https://indianbirds.thedynamicnature.com/2015/02/knob-billed-duck-sarkidiornis-melanotos.html)